# Examples of non-Kahler symplectic manifolds.

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Hi.

I want to find an example of symplectic (smooth compact) manifold $(M,\omega)$ whose Betti numbers are not unimodal, i.e.

$b_i(M) \leq b_{i+2}(M)$ fails for some $i < n$. ($ \dim{M} = 2n$.)

(Every Kahler manifold satisfies the hard Lefschetz property so that the manifold that I want to find is non-Kahler.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this book: http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0092608/page/1